# Bot that removes a member's highest role (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a command that anyone in the server can use, but i'm trying to make that when used on me the member loses his highest role and replace it with a specific one. And i'm having a bit of trouble, i can't remove roles from the member, tried the following codes:

```
role=member.top_role
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

and

```
roles=member.roles
role_list=roles[:-1]
await member.edit(roles=role_list)
```

edit:
here's the command i'm using to test if the "removing role function" is working:

```
@client.command()
async def take(ctx , member:discord.Member):
    roles = member.roles 
    roles.reverse() 
    top_role = roles[0]
    await member.remove_roles(top_role)
    await ctx.send('top role removed')
```

I tried these and nothing happened, no errors, nothing. I made some tests dividing the code in parts and all of it works ok until the parts "await member.remove_roles(role)" in the first case and "await member.edit(roles=role_list)" in the second. Am i missing something for it to work?

Comment: Does your bot have the appropriate permissions and is it's role higher than any user's potential highest role?

Comment: I gave him a role with admin. And also there's another command that only adds a role (await member.add_roles(role)) that works fine. I really don't know what's the matter with the remove_roles

Answer (score 0):

edit: answer updated.
The ctx.author is a member.
You can find everything in the official Documentation. [Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
@client.command()
async def take(ctx):
    roles = ctx.author.roles #list of roles, lowest role first
    roles.reverse() #list of roles, highest role first
    top_role = roles[0] #first entry of list
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(top_role)
    await ctx.send('top role removed')
```

Comment: It isn't working and there's no errors, i even added "await ctx.send ('removed')" and not even that happened

Comment: @Def4ltt Please update your question and insert the complete source code of your command, then it is easier to understand the problem

Comment: Done, there isn't litterally much more than what i sent already, but there's the full command i'm using to test if it removes the role or not